# Odd casting curiosity in C

Tags: c++, c

I'm a beginner to computer programming, only been doing it in basic languages for a couple years, and now I'm moving onto more complex languages like C and C++.

I discovered something in C, and I cannot wrap my head around it.
And I won't leave it alone because things that pop into my head and remain unresolved are never left unresolved.
This is the code I've began to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <math.h>;
#define pi 3.14
#define abs(v)(v<0?-v:v)
int main()
{
printf("%d",(int)ceil(abs(pi)));
}
```

Now, this is my pondering.
Why is it that this,

```
printf("%d",(int)ceil(abs( pi )));
```

returns 4 as it should,

but when I place the cast operator as so:

```
printf("%d",ceil((int)abs( pi )));
```

it returns 0?

It makes no sense to me, for it should return 4 either way, since (int)abs( pi ) returns 3, but it's still ceiled precedingly. So in essence it should say, alright, I've grabbed 3 as a casted int of abs( pi ), and now I've ceiled it, so it should return 4.

But nooo it returns 0.

Shouldn't

```
(int) ceil(abs( pi ))
```

be equivalent to

```
ceil( (int) abs( pi ) ) ? ?
```

If only programming could be as simple as saying, 'DO THIS SHIT' and then all of a sudden everything works flawlessly.

Comment: The greatest solution to this sort of problems is to enable all warnings and tell the compiler to treat them as errors (because they really are). And hey, there is no need to put `;` after `#`directives!

Comment: @user3125367 In this case it wouldn't do him no good, because printf has no type safety.

Comment: @Lundin warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]. Basically any compiler today will warn about incorrect format string, unless warnings are disabled. And enabled warnings can't do no good for sure.

Comment: @user3125367 But analysing the format string is not the compiler's task... strictly speaking I could skip stdio.h and make my own printf function (which is a bad idea, but still). The compiler shouldn't be whining about the format string then, because it has absolutely no clue about what format that is expected.

Comment: @Lundin There are various pragmas and macros to mark your function as printf-like. I'm strictly against arguing that warnings are unhelpful in this case and overall, because they practically would help in this case and overall, but I'm open to anything else. Please bring more arguments for not using them always or clarify your position.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing:

```
printf("%d",ceil((int)abs( pi )));
```

...to:

```
printf("%f",ceil((int)abs( pi )));
```

Your current problem almost certainly stems from the fact that `ceil` returns a `double` but you're telling `printf` to expect an `int`.

Of course, for C++ skip all of that and use:

```
std::cout << ceil((int)abs( pi ));
```

or:

```
std:cout << ceil(static_cast<int>(abs(pi)));
```

...and let the compiler keep track of the correct type for the conversion.

For what it's worth, I'd expect this to produce `3`, not `4`. The conversion to `int` will truncate Pi to `3`. That will then be converted to a double. Since it has no fractional part, its `ceil` will remain `3`.

Comment: But then why does it work one way and not the other? :D It's outputting 4

Comment: @user3317781: because in the other code you cast the result from `ceil` to an `int`, so what was passed to `printf` was an `int`, which is the type it expects for a `%d` format conversion.

Comment: Oh, of course. Now after all this hassle I feel like an idiot. Lol. Well, none of us start as good programmers now do we? I'm sure this is childs play to you guys xd

Comment: @user3317781: Some undoubtedly start out better than others. I think it's safe to say more make *more* mistakes as beginners than with more experience, but even with a lot of experience most of us still make some pretty silly mistakes at times.